# Am I missing an index for these slow queries?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I've tried analyzing the `EXPLAIN` but unsure if I'm missing some helpful index. Queries take 20-30 seconds across 14 million rows.

```
 CREATE TABLE `domains` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `domain` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `last_seen_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT '1980-01-01 00:00:00',
  `failures` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `domain_UNIQUE` (`domain`),
  KEY `last_seen_index` (`last_seen_at`),
  KEY `failures_index` (`failures` DESC),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15917835 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
```

my query:

```
SELECT 
                    domains.id,
                    domains.domain,
                    domains.last_seen_at,
                    domains.failures
                FROM domains 
                WHERE 
                    domains.failures < 10
                ORDER BY domains.last_seen_at ASC 
                LIMIT 1
                FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
```

explain:

```
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type  | possible_keys                            | key             | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | domains | NULL       | index | failures_index                           | last_seen_index | 5       | NULL |    2 |    50.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+---------------+
| VERSION()     |
+---------------+
| 8.0.18-google |
+---------------+
```

Comment: What can you tell us about the expected data distribution - do you expect most rows to have `failures < 10`. Do you expect that the rows which have the smallest `last_seen_at` values to have `failures < 10` ?

Comment: @AndrewSayer, a small % should have `failures > 10`, but no correlation between `last_seen_at` and `failures`. i have workers cycling through domains regularly.

Comment: So if you were to look at the rows in order with the smallest `last_seen_at` value first, you would expect to find a row which matches your `failures` predicate very soon?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

The Optimizer is between a rock and a hard place.

Using `last_seen_index` avoids the need for a sort, but might have to scan the entire table without finding even 1 row.

If most of the rows have very few "failures", using `failures_index` might lead to scanning most of the table, do a big sort, and finally delivering one row.

Since you seem to be picking up the "oldest" record and are probably going to run the same query frequently, consider "remembering where you left off" and sticking that into the `WHERE`:

```
AND last_seen_at >= ?
```

Then, the Optimizer might correctly pick `last_seen_index` as the better index.  And it would not have to scan the entire table.

Think of writing the query as the next iteration of scanning through a large table based on the timestamp.

I find the "remember where you left off" a common optimization; see big deleted, pagination, summary tables, and big alters in http://mysql.rjweb.org/

I am assuming that `last_seen_at` is updated whenever `failures` in incremented?  If no, can you add a `last_checked` timestamp?

**Run out of data**

Eventually the job will find nothing to do.  That is, it will do the select and find that it is at the "end" of the table (based on last_seen_at).  At that point, it should start over with the oldest possible date (~1970)`.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. `last_seen_at` is incremented regardless of success/failure. Unfortunately, the current schema design inserts new, never-before-seen items in with a `1970` `last_seen_at`, so i have no way to keep track of where i left off.

Comment: @d-_-b - No problem -- see what I added to my Answer.